# Display broken - what kind of USB-VGA/HDMI DisplayAdapter works with WIN 10 on Asus ZenBOOK UX390UAK

Tags: usb, hdmi, windows

I want to save my SSD of my **Asus Zenbook UX390UAK** but my Display does not work anymore. Is there a **DisplayUSB-Adapter** without need of 3rd-party Driver and works **Plug&Play with WIN 10**. If this could be done, I can save the internal SSD on an external HDD by using Acronis True Image. Thanks for any
helpful advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to install an external display to rescue your ssd. You can in most cases take the ssd out of your computer and install it in a different pc. If you still want to connect a different display, you can use this adaptor: https://www.amazon.nl/DEKNEI-Ethernet-TF-kaartlezer-compatibel-C-apparaten/dp/B08RHJF6GY/ref=asc_df_B08RHJF6GY/

Comment: Thanks but do I need to install additional drivers when using this adapter under Windows 10 or is it plug and play?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have bought such an adaptor and there were no additional drivers to install and works fine. So I need not to open the computer because it could be done only with special screwdriver.